# how to specify queue in qpid with same exchange in JMS API?

Tags: jms, amqp, qpid

I am following example as

https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/qpid/trunk/qpid/java/client/example/src/main/java/org/apache/qpid/example/Hello.java

Here they have one exchange and one queue. How to send message to different queue in same exchange ? How to specify routing information in message ?

I am using java / JMS api

Answer (score 0):

You can use topic exchange to deliver messages.
Consumer specifies routing key to a outgoing message.
Producer binds a queue to a topic type exchange with a binding key. Of course, you can bind two or more queues to one topic exchange with same binding key.
When a message with a routing key arrives in broker, the topic exchange will deliver it according to the match between routing key and binding key.

The above is the basic principle from AMQP. The rest is to implement your code in Java way.